# Disabling avx instructions with noxsave

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, avx

I'm trying to disable avx, since it doesn't let me debug in reverse order. After googling for a while I came to couple bit fixes (tried without success) and noxsave option. I'm adding `noxsave` option to the end of grub configuration file at `/etc/default/grub` and then calling  `sudo update-grub` resulting `13: /etc/default/grub: noxsave: not found`. What is wrong?

Maybe there is some flag to compile `c` files without avx instructions?

Kernel version 4.4.0-124-generic.
Disto Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: `noxsave` goes at the end of the kernel command line, not on a line by itself.  `/etc/default/grub` is a shell script which sets shell variables.

Comment: well, it killed one VM but worked for another, tnx

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does *"doesn't let me debug in reverse order"* mean?

Comment: I'm guessing OP means [reverse debugging with gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html) ?

Comment: Just for information, one can also disable AVX with `clearcpuid=156` kernel option.